# How do I make my discord bot play audio from YouTube

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, bots, discord.py

So, my question is how do I set the variable url to be what someone types after yt? For example, `!yt [youtbube link] makes url = [youtube link]`

This is my code at the moment and any help is appreciated

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def yt(ctx):
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPOUewuNKFE'

    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

Comment: What is not working in this code (after fixing the indentation)?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code, i just don't know how to make it play the link someone puts after !yt, i put my code just so people could see what I have.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, actually. Just add it as an argument to the function.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def yt(ctx, url):

    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

If you want to, you can also specify the type of the argument using a standard function annotation (`async def yt(ctx, url: str):`), but it wouldn't be very useful since the default is to pass them as strings anyways.

Comment: alternatively, instead of `yt(ctx, url)`, you can use `yt(ctx, *, url)` and that way it will just accept the rest of the message into url.

Comment: well-formed Youtube urls never have spaces in them, however, and this program can't play multiple urls separated by spaces either, so i saw no need to do that.

Comment: How would I launch this, and command the bot to play the inputted URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def yt(ctx):
        url = ctx.message.content
        url = url.strip('!yt ')

        author = ctx.message.author
        voice_channel = author.voice_channel
        vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

        player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
        player.start()
```

Answer (score -4):

I assume you already know this but there are bots out there that can do this for you. Just in case you don't, you can give it a link from YouTube and make sure that bot is in the voice channel with you. I am not sure if you are trying to get it to play different links in multiple voice channel(s) or not though. I highly doubt the bot can play different songs over multiple voice channel(s) considering it has to be in the voice channel with you.

Comment: Yeah, I know there are bots to do this but I wanted to have my bot do it :P

Comment: That makes sense. I thought about trying to make my own bot. I only play on weekends really so it wouldn't do me much good.

Comment: No, after the bot joins you in the voice channel, you can drag and drop the bot to the Stage channel. Make the bot speaker and you can leave